# EXTJS MVC sending data from one view to another

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

Am developing application using EXTJS MVC Architecture.
I have created a dataview which consists of the list of users in the system, and each item in the dataview consists of three buttons. One of them is the edit button, which on clicking opens another view. This view consists of a form where the users details can be edited. Now, what am struck in is, when i open the form, i want the users details to be loaded into the fields of the form.

So, how do i send the data from the dataview to the form so that the appropriate data, respective to the user gets loaded?

Here is the code:

Controller

```
init : function() {
    this.control({
        'button[action=addUsers ]' : {
            click : this.addUsers
        },
        '#userlist' : {
            itemclick : this.userListSelectionChange
        }
    })
},
userListSelectionChange : function(view, record, h, ind, evt) {

    console.log('user List clicked')

    var edit = evt.getTarget('a.icon-edit-32');
    var deletebt = evt.getTarget('a.icon-delete-32');

    if (edit != null) {

        var name = record.get('Name');
        console.log(name);

        this.showHWindow(record);
    }

    if (deletebt != null) {

        var name = record.get('Name');
        console.log(name);

        this.showOffWindow();
    }
},
```

When the showHWindow() method is called, the form opens, and i want the form to be loaded with the data for that particular user. And, even though its printing the correct name for

```
var name = record.get('Name');
```

Am not sure how to send this data to the form.

Also, i have tried using loadRecord method, but the fields are empty.

```
this.euWin = Ext.create('Campus.view.EditUsers');   

var f = this.getEdituserform().getForm();

    f.loadRecord(record);

    this.euWin.showWin();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:) The name in my form was different from that of the record.
I had

```
record.data.Name
```

whereas in the form i had

```
name : FName
```

I have changed to

```
name : Name
```

Thank You lontivero so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your userListSelectionChange method receives the grid row data in the 'record' parameter then, what you have to do is load the form using the form´s loadRecord method, that´s all.

Comment: Yes, i have tried that, but its not working. Will edit my code and show what i have done

Comment: can you include your form code? I am developing a big application with tons of forms and loadRecord is the way to populate them.